# how to recover/prevent a network failure when the Root peer node crashes

Tags: hyperledger

The Hyperledger-fabric documentation specifies that all VP should be linked to the root Peer node.

[Hyperledger documentation:http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Network-setup/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIZf1.png)

However at any stage, if the root peer node fail (shutdown), then the entire network (all vp) will be inaccessible.

What is the best way to handle/avoid such situation?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if the root peer node fail (shutdown), then the entire network (all
>   vp) will be inaccessible.

This is not true. The network would still be running, and still deploy, invoke transactions.

Consider for example,
If I have 3 nodes running, i.e, `vp0`, `vp1`, `vp2` with `vp0` running as a root node, and if i shutdown this root node (vp0), 
I would still be able to deploy and invoke transactions on the rest of the nodes in the network.

You can verify that the rest of the nodes are still running by executing (for each container),

```
docker exec container-id curl http://localhost:7050/network/peers
```

it will list all the current peers in the network.

`container-id` can be found by running `docker ps`

However, in order to add new nodes in the network, 
I have to specify the value of `CORE_PEER_DISCOVERY_ROOTNODE` and set it to the ip address of either `vp1` or `vp2` (vp0 is down).

Comment: Thank you for your reply . i tested it and it's working. the issue was in the port mapping. Once Again thank you .

Comment: once the VP is up and running again , it will automatically sync with the remaining VP right ? (no need to do any manual work )Thank you

Comment: yes. But this is all under the assumption that you are using `noops`. when you use `pbft` the new root node is automatically elected.